# Using PHP buffering to save PHP output to HTML in a specific directory

Tags: php, forms, buffering

I have a user HTML form on my site. On 'submit' of the form, I am using PHP buffering to save the output as an html file in my root directory.

Currently, the file generates and saves successfully, with an assigned page name it gets from one of the form fields.  So far, so good.

The following code works brilliantly to achieve that:

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
$headline=preg_replace('#[^_0-9a-zA-Z]#', '_', $_REQUEST['banner']);
?>
/* My 'Form Page' Content Here */
<?php 
echo ''; 
file_put_contents($headline . '.html', ob_get_contents());
```

However....

I would like to include a drop down selector in my form, with different 'sections', such as: "News", "Sports", "Weather", etc.... to choose a specific directory (folder) on my server, so the generated html file will save to an assigned directory.

I need help on the form field side of that, as well as the php buffering side to achieve this. I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: Would you outline _why_ you want to do this? Generally when a (post) form is submitted it will take some action and then redirect, so the output appears in a get request. If you want to create a file you can do that with file write commands, which may be preferable to using the output buffering system.

Comment: I think your use of $_REQUEST is limiting you a bit.  Why not use $_POST and get the form variables?

Comment: Our advice still is to use a simple database based approach to generate dynamic pages instead, just as we commented with your last question about this. That will save you a lot of hassle with house keeping and cleanup issues. But if you really want to go on to invest into this exotic setup, then at least take care to really clean the user provided data before you use it in server side file system operations. You will implement a huge security gap otherwise...

Comment: @JamesShaver Why is that limiting? `$_REQUEST` contains all the `$_POST` and `$_GET` parameters from the form and URL.

Comment: @arkascha How much cleaner can it get than removing all non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: And everything else involved with $_REQUEST too.  $_POST (or $_GET) would simplify the process of getting the specific select field he's after.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, true, but still nor clean, at least it is pre programmed that naming collisions will occur with that code. Non handled collisions...

Comment: @JamesShaver We use `$_REQUEST` in all our scripts, so we can easily test them by putting form parameters in the browser address bar.

Comment: Thanks arkascha I appreciate that advice. And as I mentioned yesterday, it is valid. I definitely do need to eventually get it into a true 'database' setup. However, even though I call it a 'user' form.... I will actually be the only person using using this form to post. Once it's working, in the short term, I may add posting privileges to 1 or 2 trusted employees. But I will definitely switch to a true database soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Add a directory dropdown:

```
<select name="directory">
    <option value="news">News</option>
    <option value="sports">Sports</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then use this as the directory part of the filename in the script:

```
$dir = $_REQUEST['directory'];
$valid_directories = array('news', 'sports', 'weather', ...);
if (!in_array($dir, $valid_directories)) {
    die("Invalid directory");
}
file_put_contents("$dir/$headline.html", ob_get_contents());
```